# Converting XML response from Oracle server to JSON

Tags: php, json, ajax

My company has a service that returns data about a product when a serial number is sent (not sure if it matters that it runs on an Oracle server). The service can be accessed by appending a serial number to this URL:

> https://example.com/searchserial/v1/W123456789

Since the service requires authentication, I send the serial number request from an HTML page to a PHP running on my server.

I am making this AJAX call to the PHP page from the HTML page. The **serialsearch** var is the SN entered by the user:

```
     $.ajax({
    "async": true,
    "url": "./serialsearch.php?serialsearch=" + serialsearch,
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "accept": "application/json",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
    }
  }).done(function(response) {
    var renderedHtml = template(response.SerialInfo);
    var context = $("#result").html(renderedHtml);
  });
```

The PHP looks like this:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://example.com/searchserial/v1/' . $_GET['serialsearch'];
$info = array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'Cache-control: no-cache');
$get_field_string = http_build_query($info, '', '&');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,'Authorization: Basic blahblahblahblahblahblah=');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array($get_field_string)); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);   
$exec = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($exec);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Everything works fine, except that the server returns XML only, but I need JSON so that I can plug in the response data into Handlebar templates on my HTML page.

When I test the service in Postman and select JSON, it errors out on the first character, which is usually the header sent from the server and not pure JSON. The XML view shows all the corresponding data.

Do I need to convert the XML to JSON in the PHP before sending it back to the HTML, where the AJAX call is being made from? Convert it in the HTML page? Looks like converting XML to JSON is not the most straightforward thing to do.

Comment: You should convert it in php, not in html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to do conversions in PHP side. Simply read response as XML and convert to JSON

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($exec, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
echo json_encode($xml);
```

Comment: My code now looks like this:  
`$exec = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($exec);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($exec, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
echo json_encode($xml);
curl_close($ch);
?>`
I still get the same **XML** response, no JSON.

Comment: I don't think the **simplexml_load_string** is working because the server is returning a big header (e.g., **HTTP/1.1 200 OK**, the date, server type, content-length, and so on) in the XML before the XML begins. The XML doesn't start until line 9 in the XML response. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Update: Changed the header line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);`